# XSLT (XPath 1.0) test last and second last character

Tags: xslt, xpath

I wish to make tests in an XPath. In my test I should exclude all values that end with a '9' where the second last character is not a number.

For example:

ABCD9 (should be excluded from the output)
ABC12 (should be included)

My current code is:

`<xsl:when test="('9' = substring(sAMAccountName, string-length(sAMAccountName))) and (string(number(substring(sAMAccountName, string-length(sAMAccountName)-1,1))) = NaN)">`

I'm pretty sure my first part `'9' = substring(sAMAccountName, string-length(sAMAccountName))`

is correct, but as soon as I add the second part, it's not working.

I'm not an expert in XSLT, so maybe it's not possible to create a second condition like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `string-length(translate(substring(sAMAccountName, string-length(sAMAccountName)-1,1)), '0123456789', '') = 0` to check it is a digit or `string-length(translate(substring(sAMAccountName, string-length(sAMAccountName)-1,1)), '0123456789', '') = 1` to check the second to last character is not a digit.